# Issue with Vector3.Dot on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Have some issue with getting moving direction on android device. 
Using the following code, I am trying to get the player direction through the collider (like a door).

```
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    Vector3 direction = other.transform.position - transform.position;

    if (Vector3.Dot (transform.forward, direction) > 0) {
       print ("Moving Back");
    } 
    if (Vector3.Dot (transform.forward, direction) < 0) {
       print ("Moving Forward");
    } 
}
```

But when I launch app on android  and player moving forward it defines like I move in opposite direction.
I thought that when app make calculation it uses local coordinate system.

In general when player moving right(image 1 below) - the same with local coordinate system, it should be defined as "forward"(iOS, Unity works fine), but on android it calculates like "opposite direction".
It seems the android makes calculation using global coordinates. Am I right or what I am doing wrong? How can I make android to define direction by local coordinates of collider.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Also I want to show you how looks the collider in diff coordinate systems
[image]
[image: global coordinate system]

Comment: hm that sounds strange. transform.forward is (according to unitys documentation) in world space. Other than that I am actually a little surprised that it is working as expected in unity: if you are moving "forward" then the dot product of `transform.forward` and `direction` is positive, not negative

Comment: @xyLe_ Ok thanks, will check everything once more